# Multiple tabs in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a question here, can you please explain.

Why during opening of second and third windows we are calling the getWindowHandles following the below

```
win = driver.getWindowHandles();
iterate = win.iterator();
first_window = iterate.next();
System.out.println(first_window);  // first handle
second_window = iterate.next();
System.out.println(second_window);  // second handle
```

can't we call directly the below during the operation of third window

```
String Third_window = iterate.next();
System.out.println(Third_window);
driver.switchTo().window(Third_window);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your webapplication has multiple windows as you navigate through it, we need to handle multiple windows using getWindowHandles() method. which returns the unique alphanumeric id (String object) of each window those are opened or associated or instantiated through any link/button click with your Webdriver object.

getWindowHandles() returns the list of window handle of all the current windows.

So whenever you call getWindowHandles() on your driver object. it stores the unique window handles of all the opened window including you parent window handle.You can switch to each window one by one inside loop and look for specific webelement and if found you can work on that window (in your case 3rd window).By doing so you will make sure that your code will work on correct window and not just based on assumed numbering of the windows.Also you need to store the parent window handle so you can switch back once your work on other window is done.

Code:

```
String parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> childWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterator = childWindows.iterator();


while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    String child = iterator.next();

    if(!child.equalsIgnoreCase(parentWindowHandle))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(child);
        try
        {
            if (driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_some_element_on_that_window")).isDisplayed())
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) // you can catch the specific exoection NoSuchElement or other
        {
            System.out.println("Element not found."+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

// rest of code to work on desired window

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandle);
```

Hope this helps:)

Comment: While it’s true that one cannot use the iterator in the call to `switchTo().window()`, it is distinctly untrue that the order of the handles from `getWindowHandles()` are in the order the windows were opened. In fact, the window handles are explicitly in _no_ specified order, and that order should specifically _not_ be relied upon. You should change your answer to reflect that.

Comment: @JimEvans Thanks. I was under the impression that it is stored sequentially (though Sets in java does not element in sequential order). You are correct. We should not rely upon the order, as we may not be aware on which window it will pick. Its better to find specific element inside the desired window and work on that.

Comment: Now your sample code needs an exception handler around the `if (driver.findElement(...))` statement, or it’s likely to throw if the element isn't on that page.

Comment: @NitishKshirsagar how to enhance the while loop to support 4-5 browser window.
In that case whether iterator method will be useful ?

Comment: @PrashanthNagendra you can have multiple if statement to check the specific element on each of your browser window and can give call to another method by passing your driver and window handle to carry out the rest of the operation on that page. but again as a first step you have to check the presence of some element on each of the window using isDisplayed() which might throw the exception so you need to add try-catch to each if statement. Iterator method looks efficient to me.:)